# How to use JPA EntityManager in java SE applications

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I'm working on a java SE application and I want to use JPA EntityManager for managing database operations. From my searches, I found that there is need to make a `persistence.xml` file. But I don't know where should I put it. My search results say it should be place in the `webRoot\META-INF`, but my project it's not a J2EE project, so it has not webRoot or META-INF directories. Here is my code for getting entity manager:

```
 private static EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unitName");
 protected EntityManager entityManager =  entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
```

But this always causes `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` exception and return me this message:

```
No Persistence provider for EntityManager named unitName
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: The JPA spec says simply META-INF, so put it in META-INF from the root of the classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can CREATE a file META-INF like that:

[image]

but if you are using Netbeans, so when you create **Entity Classes From Database**, that folder will be created automaticly, you can try that.

good luck.

Comment: Thank you. The solution `create Entity Classes From Database` solved my problem. But is there anyway to use entity manager without `persistence.xml`?

Comment: I dont think you can use JPA or Hibernet without persistence.xml

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Hibernate, you can see its [Tutorial Using the Java Persistence API (JPA)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa.html):

> In Java™ SE environments the persistence provider (Hibernate in this case) is required to locate all JPA configuration files by classpath lookup of the META-INF/persistence.xml resource name.

Put the persistence.xml to

- `./src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` if you use maven.
- `./src/META-INF/persistence.xml` if you don't use maven.

Once done, the above tutorial also tells you how to configure the following and use JPA step by step. Check [here](https://gist.github.com/mortezaadi/8619433) if you need any persistence template.